# Find Missing Dates in My table

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a make table that figures daily pride and assigns the current date to each line.  I want to be able to run a query to pull all pride numbers from 06/01/2016 to 06/30/2016 and then run a query to find the dates in which there was no pride information entered if we could factor out weekends that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, create a table [CalendarBusinessDay] with columns [CalendarDate] as Date/Time and [BusinessDay] as Yes/No where weekend dates are False.
Add the appropriate month's data with a simple code loop.

Run this query:

```
select 
    CalendarBusinessDay.CalendarDate
from 
    CalendarBusinessDay
left join MyTable
    on CalendarBusinessDay.CalendarDate = MyTable.MyDate
where CalendarBusinessDay.BusinessDay = True
    and MyTable.MyDate is null;
```